# How can I get my DateTime object to format as ISO 8601 with the offset on the end?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm having trouble getting my date time into exactly this format:

`2017-01-27T14:58:00+00:00`

If I do this:

`date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK");`

I get `0001-01-01T00:00:00` missing the last `+00:00`

If I do `.ToUniversalTime()` I end up with `0001-01-01T00:00:00Z`

How can I append the correct value of `+00:00`?

If I do `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK");` I get `2017-02-06T12:00:18+00:00` which is the format I want.

Comment: I am in UTC+01:00 and it shows for me. I see you reside in the UK, aka UTC+00:00, so I reckon it is trimmed for simplicity. Do you need it to show even like that?

Comment: Have a look at the formats here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm using a 3rd party API and the date function is not working, and their developer has told me to send the date in that exact format. I reckon I'll just end up doing string concatenation, although why it works with DateTime.Now I don't know - some culture info perhaps but I couldn't find how to include that.

I have to be wary of daylight savings time though.

Comment: @NibblyPig, encapsulate the DateTime in a DateTimeOffset and it should work

Comment: That does add the +00:00 but I am not sure if that's because 00 is the default, and it might be problematic during daylight savings time. But that's a problem for future me. Thanks!

Comment: This happens because your `date` has `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. Not giving time zone information is correct in this case: there is no time zone. If your `DateTime` has `DateTimeKind.Local` (as `DateTime.Now` always does), the specifier does output a time zone. (If it's `DateTimeKind.Utc`, you get `Z`.) You can use `DateTime.SpecifyKind` to override the kind for existing `DateTime` instances that you know to be local.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. You could add that as an answer, of the behaviour and to use SpecifyKind otherwise.